# I'd like to know how Unity moves sprites without using Resource Manager

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Unity is trying to retrieve images stored in a folder other than the resource folder.
I don't know what to do because it's not included in the resource folder, so I can't call it to the resource manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can't, because Unity will cut off the files outside `Resources` while Build process. Even if you can access the file in editor with relative file path, the file will gone after the build, which will result `FileNotFoundException` or something. Briefly, `Resources` is a special folder name recognized by unity, to tell which files should be included in build process.

I think there are three choices to manage resources:

- Using `Resources` folder

Which is pretty simple, easy, and old way. I think this method is pretty outdated, but it's still a valid option and good for Unity newbies.

- Using [AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html)

Unity will process your resource files in it's own way, which will optimize the saving or managing performance. If you have not tried this, you may have to read the tutorials about AssetBundle.

- Using `StreamingAssets` folder

`StreamingAssets` is also a special folder name for Unity. Any file in this folder will be kept even after build, which means you can use normal `System.IO` file system. For example, `Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "myimage.png")` to get a path to your image. This makes your game highly modifiable for not only you, but also the other players, which means the game becomes very suitable for making *mods*.

By the way, there are another option called [Addressable](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@0.4/manual/index.html), but since it's pretty new feature I don't know much of it :(